# Application development Windows Embedded Compact 7.0 for Motorola MC32NO

Tags: embedded, motorola, windows-embedded-compact, motorola-emdk

I am trying to get started on application development for my Motorola MC32N0 device running Windows Embedded Compact 7.0.

[This tutorial](http://embedded101.com/Blogs/SamuelPhung/entryid/201/Windows-Embedded-Compact-7-Getting-Started-Part-1-Introduction) explains that I need a Board Support Package (BSP), however I am unable to find this on the [Zebra website](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Mobile+Networks+RFID+and+BarCode+Scanners/Mobile+Computers/Handheld+Computers/MC3200_US-EN). Is a BSP available for the Motorola MC32N0, and where can I find it?

Another question, during the installation of Platform Builder 7.0 I used a trial license key. Now if I deploy the build output to my device, will it replace the OS that is already installed, or will it just deploy the application?

I am new to Windows CE, but have a background in web development and WinForms.

Comment: It took me only two search requests to find https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/XU-EN/Mobile+Networks+RFID+and+BarCode+Scanners/Mobile+Computers/Handheld+Computers/MC3200_US-EN and there is the BSP https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/XU-EN/Resolution?solutionId=99751&productDetailGUID=35e9e6d089b86410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=96d05645aa79f310VgnVCM10000081c7b10aRCRD -- For WinForms development you need Visual Studio 2008 Prof. and then install the BSP to get a new target in VS for the CE7 device. There are lots of information about ComapctFramework.

Comment: yea i found this page but which package is BSP ? i thought this is BSP https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/XU-EN/Resolution?solutionId=99751&productDetailGUID=35e9e6d089b86410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=96d05645aa79f310VgnVCM10000081c7b10aRCRD but it isn't. it's just a hotfix for the OS. I want a BSP for targeting that device.

Comment: You are right, I was to fast and looked over it. Please see the "Platform SDK v2.0 for MC32N0 CE 7.0" at https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/XU-EN/Resolution?solutionId=97608&productDetailGUID=35e9e6d089b86410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=96d05645aa79f310VgnVCM10000081c7b10aRCRD

Comment: You also need "EMDK for .NET v2.9" at https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/XU-EN/Resolution?solutionId=97036&productDetailGUID=35e9e6d089b86410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=96d05645aa79f310VgnVCM10000081c7b10aRCRD if you want to write WinForm apps with device feature support (scanning etc).

Comment: It says for C/C++ but i need for C#.Net , Are you sure this is the BSP (Board Support Package) ?

Comment: Anyway this SDK should add the CE7 target. At least the Readme should tell you what you need else. I can not download this, as they changed from Motorola to Zebra and require a contract or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For C/C++ *application* development, Visual Studio 2008 and [the Motorola SDK](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/XU-EN/Resolution?solutionId=97608&productDetailGUID=35e9e6d089b86410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=96d05645aa79f310VgnVCM10000081c7b10aRCRD) will suffice.

BSP's on the other hand are for developers working on low-level code such as the kernel OAL and device drivers. Platform Builder 7.0 is a plug-in to Visual Studio 2008 that enables building and debugging BSP code, and is not required for application development either.

If you only intend to develop C# applications, you may not even need the Motorola SDK, but could target just a generic Windows CE device in Visual Studio.

Comment: Then how can i access `Symbol` libraries if i don't have Motorola SDK ? And if i somehow manage to do that, how it will be deployed to my device ? According to tutorial i have to transfer the image to device which will overwrite the default OS IMO.

Comment: Sure, if the Motorola SDK includes C# libraries that you intend to use, then you'll need to install it. However, as you will be doing application development and not kernel/driver development you will not need the BSP, and should completely ignore Part 1 of the tutorial. The relevant bits for .NET application development are in Part 4. Deploying your own application from Visual Studio will not overwrite the OS as you won't be transferring an 'image', but just the .exe and .dll's (if any) that you have created.

Comment: Hope so but if anything goes wrong is there any backup that i can take of my device and restore it back afterwards ? Can you give me any other tutorial that answers my problems ?

Comment: Have you deployed yourself any solution like this to a device ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the MC32N0 specifically so can't help you with backup and restore. If the device has a persistent registry and/or file system there's always a risk of messing things up and making it unable to boot. That said, it is unlikely that anything you do in VS2008 would have that effect. The SDK documentation (or user manual) should explain how to perform a factory reset, but I don't think you will need it. Yes, I've worked with WinCE and the .NET CF for a number of years, but as I mentioned not the MC32N0 specifically.